# unable to install Ubuntu 15.10. installer freezes

Tags: system-installation, 15.10

I have been wanting to install Ubuntu on my machine that is already running Windows 10. I have been at it all day and cant seem to find any information on the issue that I am having.
I can boot to the CD or USB with no problems but when I select any of the options on the screen (Run without installing etc.)it spits this out and locks up .

[image: Picture 1]

My Rig:

```
Motherboard: Asus Sabertooth z97 Mark 1 
Processor:   Intel i7-4790k @4.00GHz
Memory:      32GB DDR3
GPU:         GeForce GTX 980
```

I'm sure that its probably something simple that I'm missing. if anyone has any ideas about this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as a corrupted iso.

Compare the checksum of the .iso image that you downloaded to the published values at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes.

WinMD5Free is a freeware Windows tool I've used for this.

I've run into this while using Chrome to download the iso files on Windows. I've since used both Edge and Firefox to download isos with checksums that match.